How to protect pages in Next app when using client auth (Firebase SDK)
In my Next.js app, I manage authentication on the client side. I would like to know what solution I can use to protect my client pages from being accessed by unauthenticated users. Additionally, I want to prevent authenticated users from being redirected to authentication pages.
Auth:
const Auth = ({ type }: { type: AuthType }) => {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { isValid },
  } = useForm<Inputs>();

  const { mutate, isPending, error } = useAuth(type);

  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<Inputs> = (data) => mutate(data);

  return (
    <div className={styles.authForm}>
      <div className={styles.header}>
        <h1>{type}</h1>
        <p>
          {type === "Login"
            ? "Login to get back to your account"
            : "Register to start chatting with people"}
        </p>
      </div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        {type === "Register" && (
          <Field
            placeholder="Name"
            name="name"
            register={register}
            rules={{
              required: true,
              minLength: 2,
              maxLength: 25,
            }}
            isPending={isPending}
          />
        )}
        <Field
          placeholder="Email address"
          name="email"
          isPending={isPending}
          register={register}
          rules={{
            required: true,
            pattern: {
              value: /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}$/i,
              message: "Invalid email address",
            },
          }}
        />
        <Field
          placeholder="Password"
          type="password"
          name="password"
          register={register}
          isPending={isPending}
          rules={{
            required: true,
          }}
        />
        {error && <p>{error.message}</p>}
        <Button isPending={isPending} isValid={isValid} />
        {type === "Login" ? (
          <Link href="register">Register</Link>
        ) : (
          <Link href="login">Login</Link>
        )}
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};


Hook to auth user:
const useAuth = (type: AuthType) => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const mutation = useMutation({
    mutationFn: (data: Inputs) => {
      return type === "Login"
        ? authService.loginUser(data)
        : authService.registerUser(data);
    },
    onSuccess: () => router.replace("/"),
  });

  return mutation;
};

Hook to get current user:
const useCurrentUser = () => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState<User | null>(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsub = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      setCurrentUser(user);
      setLoading(false);
    });

    return () => unsub();
  }, []);

  return { currentUser, loading };
};

